# Reliable Source of Heat for Underwater Society?

Tags: society, technology, environment, underwater

This society consists of various peoples and fantasy races, but most of them have heat requirements similar to humans. What would a reliable source of heat for this society be? Bonus points if this heat also provides light.

Additional Info...

- Approximately 8000-10,000 feet (2.5 - 3 km) under water on the ocean floor.
- Everything is surrounded and covered by water.
- Natives have gills and need to "breath" the water.
- They have visitors and tourists that aren't adjusted to the ocean depths and need additional compensation (not a seperate question, just a note for the requirements).
- The output area for the heat needs to be relatively safe.
- We'll focus on city areas which are vaguely similar to modern "big" cities (ie skyscrapers, city layout, etc).
- Technology level is that of the "Advanced Ancient Acropolis". http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdvancedAncientAcropolis

Edit - The duplicate suggestion, while certainly containing useful information, doesn't address the question on the same scale required for this question.

Comment: That deep underwater? Volcanos or dead biomass from above, maybe in methane form

Comment: This is a dupe, give me a minute.

Comment: Is it the case that this source of energy can be moved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer that exists in nature: [hydrothermal vents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent).

> Water emerges from these vents at temperatures ranging from 60 °C (140 °F) up to as high as 464 °C (867 °F).

The pressure from high-temp vents could be directed into pipes to allow controlled heating of spaces throughout a city, with excess heat/pressure being bled off outside the city.

These vents, and the magma systems that heat them, are a potential heat source as well as a potential source of minerals.

Comment: Not just that but the heat and pressure differentials are a potential source of mechanical power, through something as simple as a Stirling heat engine, for the purpose of driving mechanical pumps, circulation of fresh water, waste disposal systems and other more commercial enterprises like mechanical transportation and delivery; e.g. an underwater trolley system. Why swim for miles when the trolley can get you there in a few minutes?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a source of heat that could survive underwater. A few ideas come to mind.

Plasma. Plasma would not need to consume oxygen to heat things up. A device that could heat up fuel to plasma state isn't too far from reality. In fact, we've been using such things in metal machining. Though it might burn *too* hot.

Lasers. Lasers, if powerful enough and concentrated, can burn through metals. This one has an advantage of being more controllable. as you can choose how much power you're putting into the laser.